# Django admin: How to redirect to child's model's view from parent?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have two django models that are registered with the admin. Let us consider an example below :

```
#parent
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    #some relevant fields
...

#child
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturers = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="manufacturers)
    # some relevant fields
```

Both these models are registered with the admin. So in the admin view the list for Manufacturer is displayed. Now I want that if someone clicks on the manufacturer name, it should redirect to the car's list with all those car's listed who has that Manufacturer as parent.
Is it possible to achieve this? If so, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
#HTML admin
{% for man in manufacturer %}
<a href="{% url 'carview' %}?man_id={{manufacturer.pk}}">{{manufacturer.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}

#views.py
def carview(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cars = Car.objects.filter(manufacturer=request.GET.get(man_id))
        context = {'cars':cars}
        return render(request, 'cars', context)

#HTML cars
{% for car in cars %}
{{car.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Of course you have to make the context for your admin view. And in your Car class you forgot to name the manufacturer field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this using of inline in Django Admin.

```
from django.contrib import admin

class CarInline(admin.TabularInline):
      model = Car

class ManufacturerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [
           CarInline,
      ]
```

[See Inline model admin Django official Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)